# Scroll not moving after adding Text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, textarea

I'm adding some text to a textarea by using JS everytime I click on a button. The thing is that everytime the text is added, the scroll goes to top of the textarea and I don't want that. I don't want the scroll to move automatically when I add the content.

This is part of my code:

```
const textarea = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
let data = "new content added";
textarea.innerHTML = data + textarea.innerHTML;
```

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a particular line in your button event Listener

```
textarea.scrollTo(0,textarea.scrollHeight)
```

Overall code will look somewhat similar to this

```
    const textarea = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
    
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",() => {
      let data = "new content added";
      textarea.innerHTML = data + textarea.innerHTML;
      textarea.scrollTo(0,textarea.scrollHeight)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me. I only added the Scroll Height of both positions (before the content added and after the content added), made a rest between both of them and the result gave me the current position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just set your scroll position everytime you click on your button. So you can put this piece of code in another function and call it after your desired text is loaded.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```